# First Python Object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have done object oriented coding before in Java before but this is my first time trying it in Python.  I have a Optics class at a University that constantly seems to have linear regression fits involved.  So I decided to just create a simple object that I can use to make a linear fit without much hassle.  That said I am not on the up and up on Python objects and is so far proving to be a little difficult.

Everything seems to work well at this point, except for one thing I will get to, but I was wanting some feed back in my venture to Python Objects.  One thing that seems difficult is assigning new values to class variables.  Another is I don't quite understand what the self parameter in the methods is used for (it almost seemed like it was equivalent to 'this' in Java).  Anyway here is my class thus far:

```
__author__ = 'tristan'


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


class LinearFit:

__xdata = None
__ydata = None
__xerror = None
__yerror = None

def __init__(self, xdata, ydata, xerror = None, yerror = None):
    LinearFit.__xdata = xdata
    LinearFit.__ydata = ydata
    LinearFit.__xerror = xerror
    LinearFit.__yerror = yerror

def printxdata(self):
    print LinearFit.__xdata
```

Here is a testing program as I go along:

```
__author__ = 'tristan'

from LinearFit import LinearFit

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
z = LinearFit(x, y)
print z.printxdata()
```

My output is:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
None
```

This is my main problem right now is why does it print out None (the issue I alluded to earlier)?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method doesn't return anything explicitly, so it returns `None`. And then you print it. If you meant to return the value then you should use `return LinearFit.__xdata[:]` instead. And you should reconsider your use of initial double underscores.

Comment: Should probably also reconsider storing everything on the class instead of the instance.

Comment: How can I just make a method that prints and doesn't try to return anything.  If it were Java one could just use the void keyterm in the method and it wouldn't return anything. Is there something similar or will it always return. Also why should I not keep the double dash in the front? I want to keep it private and client friendly as possible.

Comment: You **cannot** return "nothing". But you can avoid printing it. And there's nothing private about initial double underscores.

Comment: So as a Java person you often use private constantly but I guess it doesn't work the same in Python so I will avoid using it.  Also on the topic of the return issue.  If were essentially mix types of a string and floating point into the return it would work the same as how I printed it?

Comment: It will work however you tell it to. But don't mix return types if possible.

Answer (score 1):

"Return" and "Print" are different things. It's like asking someone to GIVE you something or to SHOW you something.

```
# first executes printxdata()
# then returns the result
print z.printxdata()

# a longer and easier to understand way:
result = z.printxdata()
print result
```

Result will be None, since printxdata() does not return anything, it just prints in the screen.

```
// in Java
public void printxdata() {
    // it just PRINTS
    System.out.println(LinearFit.__xdata)
    // NO return statement
}
```

Sorry for the redundancies, I just tried to make it clear.

Edit:
Since printxdata() already prints something, you don't need to use print again:

```
# replace this
print z.printxdata()

# with this
z.printxdata()
```